# Linq or better approach to extract values from string[]

Tags: c#, linq

I have this input string and need to extract values of Uid, pwd and Dsn attributes...
I am splitting the values using ; char and then replacing Uid ="" and that's how I am reading values for other attributes too...

```
String[] test = "Uid=test;Pwd=abc;dsn=xxx".split(';')

id = test[0].Replace("Uid=", "");
pwd = test[0].Replace("Pwd", "");
datasrc = test[0].Replace("Dsn", "");
```

Is there any better approach to extract values from string[] ?

Comment: a regular expression would be best before splitting.

Comment: shouldn't it be `test[0]` for Uid, `test[1]` for pwd and `test[2]` for dns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `Dictionary<String, String>` and, yes, *Linq* to materialize the initial string into it:

```
  string test = "Uid=test;Pwd=abc;dsn=xxx";

  Dictionary<string, string> dict = test
    .Split(';')
    .Select(item => item.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  ...

  var id = dict["Uid"];
  var pwd = dict["Pwd"];
  var datasrc = dict["Dsn"]; // please, notice that the name is case insensitive
```

Comment: yeah Dictionary is more suitable! +1 :)

Comment: The equality comparer is only used while creating the dictionary (it won't make the dictionary lookups case-insensitive).

Comment: @Eren Ersönmez: and `.ToDictionary` *creates* the dictionary (better term *materializes* `IEnumerable<T>` into the dictionary) and it does create case-insensitive one. Please, run the code

Answer (score 0):

You can project after splitting and then split on **=** character and pick the second index, but it would only work, if the string is guaranteed to be always in this format, then this should work for you:

```
var result = "Uid=test;Pwd=abc;dsn=xxx".Split(';')
                                       .Select(x=> x.Split('=')[1]);
```

### Result:

[image]

See the [working DEMO Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/icVcJd)